# Limit verify that = 0

Tags: limits

I am not able to verify this limit, could someone show a step by step solution to this question?

$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{((h+x)+2)^{3/5}-(x+2)^{3/5}}{h}
$$
evaluated at $x=-2$.

I wish to see it derived without using derivatives.

Comment: Don't you want $x=2$?

Comment: Don't you have any conditions in h? I guess h should be approaching 0 (you're taking the derivative of $(x-2)^{3/5}$)

Comment: Are you trying to look at $((x-2)^{3/5})'$ evaluated at $x=-2$?

Comment: Im sorry was a typo, it was negative where it was suppose to be positive. Could you guys have a look at it now.

Comment: I have corrected it!

Comment: If you don't have any conditions in h you just have (if h is not approaching 0): $\frac{h^{3/5}}{h}=h^{-2/5}$

Comment: Off, of course. Limit as h-> approaches zero. I also want to see how its done without using L.H rule by derivatives.

Comment: @ALEXANDER it is undefined not 0. Please look at my answer

Comment: The functions is $(x+2)^\frac{3}{5}$, not $(x-2)^\frac{3}{5}$

Comment: In the answer manual it states that the limit is -2. In other words I can not verify that it is 0.

Comment: @ALEXANDER then your problem is written incorrectly. Please update. My solution below is correct.

Comment: Okey, looked back at it several times now, it is correctly stated. First error Ive found in the text book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *evaluate* the limit at a particular value of $x$, simply plug in that number and then take the limit.  That is, you get

$$\lim_{h\to0}{((h-2)+2)^{3/5}-(-2+2)\over h}=\lim_{h\to0}{h^{3/5}-0\over h}=\lim_{h\to0}{1\over h^{2/5}}$$

which, being of the form $1/0$, is undefined.

Note, I italicized *evaluate* to emphasize a conceptual difference between $f'(a)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$.

Comment: I see that DanZimm posted a virtually identical answer while I was taking my time writing up my own.  Great minds and all that....

Comment: What I actually did was use telepathy and just have insane typing skills ;P

Comment: @DanZimm, LOL. I wondered who was tapping my brainwaves.  Please return any unwanted thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

Without using derivatives you wish to find
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{((x+h)+2)^{3/5}-(x+2)^{3/5}}{h} \tag{1}
$$
at $x = -2$ then we can evaluate
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{((-2+h)+2)^{3/5}-(-2+2)^{3/5}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} h^{-2/5} \to \infty
$$
Note however that if you wish to find the limit as $x \to -2$ of $(1)$ then you want to consider
$$
\lim_{x \to -2} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{((x+h)+2)^{3/5}-(x+2)^{3/5}}{h} = \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{3}{5}(x+2)^{-2/5} \to \infty
$$
but you come to the same issue of getting arbitrarily large values as you get closer and closer to your limit point.

Comment: I think this is exactly what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

This limit is equal to finding the derivative for a function:

$$f(x) = (x+2)^\frac{3}{5}$$

At $x = -2$

So, $$f'(x) = \frac{3}{5}*(x+2)^\frac{-2}{5}$$

$$f'(-2) = \frac{3}{5*0} =  \text{undefined}$$

You are incorrect.